# shadow warning with generic lambda g++

Tags: c++, lambda, warnings

g++ (4.9) gives shadow warning for the following code:

```
class Invoke {
public:
    template <typename F>
    void invoke (F&& f)
    {
        void *p;

        f(p);
    }
};

int main ()
{
    Invoke in;

    auto fn = [](auto *p)
    {
    };

    in.invoke(fn);
}
```

If I compile this, I get the following warning with -Wshadow enabled:

```
invoke.cpp: In instantiation of ‘main()::<lambda(auto:1*)> [with auto:1 = void]’:
invoke.cpp:10:12:   required from ‘void Invoke::invoke(F&&) [with F = main()::<lambda(auto:1*)>&]’
invoke.cpp:22:17:   required from here
invoke.cpp:18:25: warning: declaration of ‘p’ shadows a previous local [-Wshadow]
     auto fn = [](auto *p)
                         ^
invoke.cpp:8:15: note: shadowed declaration is here
         void *p;
               ^
```

Now from my perspective, the variable "p" in both these cases are in different context, so it should not give a warning. if I have "void *" in place of "auto *", there is no warning. Is this expected?

Comment: As of GCC 6.x, that warning does not show up anymore, so I suspect this may be a compiler bug in your old version of GCC.

Comment: Hmm looks like that. Its terribly annoying. Thanks!